# Launcher.LaunchFileAsync() and dealing with internet security settings

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

The application I'm working on downloads files from our server and then launches them. While many files are working perfectly, I'm having some problems when launching files that Microsoft has decided are "unsafe", these are normal files (.doc/.xml) but downloaded from our server and now with a **Unknown publisher** stamp.

**Code:**

```
bool res = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file, options);
if (!res)
{
    options.DisplayApplicationPicker = true;
    options.TreatAsUntrusted = true;
    res = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file, options);
    if (!res)
    {
        await Util.ShowErrorMessage("Unable to open file");
    }
}
```

As you can see from the code, when the initial launch fails I try to re-launch it this time with a 'TreatAsUntrusted' flag to let Windows warn the user and thus hoping I will get access to launch the file if the user "OK"s the warning. This does not work either.

Is there anyway for me to mark the file as trusted? or can I launch it anyway somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the wget for windows circumvent this problem. For wget you need to download `wget.exe`. It uses the libraries `libssl, libiconv2, libintl3`. I tested it and got it to work, I also packagaed wget and the libraries to `https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5402101/Desktop.zip`, so you wont have to google+download+unzip.

For download a file write `wget.exe www.mydomain.com/myfile`. Relevant options for you may include:

1. `-O mydoc.doc`, saving the file as mydoc.doc, no matter what the file was named by the server.
2. `-c` continues to download the file, if it was interrupted.

I know this is properly what you thought of as solution, but it works :)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can you link external libraries like that in a Windows Store-app?

Comment: I have no idea, my first reaction is "Please delete windows 8", but I guess that is not a valid answer for your question :D

Comment: Wasn't my question, just think I've heard somewhere that you can't use non-managed libraries but I've never tested it myself.